# Why isn't node SerialPort Readline parser working?

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port, node-serialport

I've got an Arduino sending very basic messages:

```
Serial.print('R');
Serial.println(1);
```

or

```
Serial.print('R');
Serial.println(2);
```

I'm trying to read each line using node.js and the SerialPort module but I get inconsistent results:

```
Data: <Buffer 52 31 0d 0a> R1

Data: <Buffer 52 32 0d 0a> R2

Data: <Buffer 52 31 0d 0a> R1

Data: <Buffer 52 32 0d 0a> R2

Data: <Buffer 52 31 0d 0a> R1

Data: <Buffer 52 32 0d 0a> R2

Data: <Buffer 52 31 0d 0a> R1

Data: <Buffer 52 32 0d 0a> R2

Data: <Buffer 52> R
Data: <Buffer 31 0d 0a> 1

Data: <Buffer 52 32 0d 0a> R2
```

And here's how I've tried to parse:

```
this.port = new SerialPort(portName, {
            baudRate: baudRate,
            autoOpen:false,
            flowControl: false,
            parser: new Readline("\r\n")
        });

        this.port.open(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
            }

            console.log("port open!");

        });

        this.port.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err.message);
        })

        this.port.on('open', function() {
            console.log("open event called");
        });

        this.port.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('Data:', data,data.toString('utf8'));
        });
```

In short: I'm expecting `R1`, `R2` messages coming in consistently, not split up like this:

```
Data: <Buffer 52> R
Data: <Buffer 31 0d 0a> 1
```

I'm passing (`"\r\n"` / `0x0d 0x0a`) to `Readline`. What am I missing ?
How can I get consistent new line parsing using SerialPort in node ?

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I tried `parser: new Readline("\n")` beforehand but didn't seem to make a difference. I've set it to `\r\n` because that's what I see in the data buffer node sees(`0d 0a`) for some reason

Comment: Mh, maybe because you are attaching events on the port, instead of the parser? Look at the example: https://node-serialport.github.io/node-serialport/global.html#Parsers (it is only an idea, I'm not sure about this, but the port may receive data in chunk, while the parser is not ready yet or it is still waiting data)

Comment: @MatteoRagni adding the 'data' listener on the parser works. I thought I could get away with specifying the parser in the `SerialPort` constructor and simply listening to the parsed data on the serial port directly. Please provide the answer bellow so it can be marked. Additionally, if you have any suggestions to keep the syntax elegant that would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the solution to your problem requires to bind an event on the `parser` object, while you're currently listening it on the `port` object. Data that arrives trough the port is not always terminated by `0x0d 0x0a` (*). Those two byte are a string terminator signal for the `ReadLine` parser only.

Thus, maybe you should write this listener in your code instead:

```
// I'm not actually sure where parser lives, I'm not
// in the condition of trying by myself...
this.port.parser.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Data:', data,data.toString('utf8'));
});
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestion to make the syntax more elegant, and for my standard this solution is more elegant than create a function that redirects bindings for you. It depends on your application though, and at the moment I don't have enough information to suggest a possible better solution.

(*) In the first (wrong) comment that I immediately deleted, I asked why you put both byte as termination to the line `0x0d 0x0a (\r\n)`, and not simply `0x0a (\n)` but the [`Serial.println`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/) method actually writes both bytes by default.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem. I've been looking at online articles and the official documentation for over 2 hours until I found your answer. Everywhere I looked I was missing the tiny detail that they're invoking the `on("data")` function on the parser, not the port. I'm not sure whether I should laugh or cry. Thanks a lot!